# AFNetworking 3 Async image download queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, asynchronous, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking for all my communication with my server, everything is put in a separate class called 'APIConnector'.

I'm trying to download a User. When i have the user id i can generate a URL but i have no idea which users i get from the server before i receive them. The code i have right now looks like this:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *httpManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
AFHTTPSessionManager *imageManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager]; //Used for posting to the server
    [httpManager POST:url parameters:dict progress:nil
              success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
                  UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
                  if (isUser) {
                      NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray new];
                      int i = 1;
                      for (id userResult in responseObject) {
                          User *user = [[User alloc] initWithId:[userResult valueForKey:@"index"] name:[userResult valueForKey:@"name"]];
                          user.imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image/?index=%@&imgIndex=0",backendURL,user.userID];
                          [users addObject:user];
                          if (i == [responseObject count]) {
                              success(users);
                          }
                          i++;
                      }
```

I've done some iterations changing a few things, having tried it like this and also like this but with operations:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *imageManager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager]; //Used for posting to the server
    [httpManager POST:url parameters:dict progress:nil
              success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask  * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
                  UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
                  if (isUser) {
                      NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray new];
                      int i = 1;
                      for (id userResult in responseObject) {
                          User *user = [[User alloc] initWithId:[userResult valueForKey:@"index"] name:[userResult valueForKey:@"name"]];
                          user.imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url to image"];
                          [users addObject:user];
                          if (i == [responseObject count]) {
                              success(users);
                          }
                          i++;
                      }
                      NSMutableArray *usersWithImage = [NSMutableArray new];
                      for (int i = 0; i < users.count;i++) {
                          User *userImg = [users objectAtIndex:i];
                          NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image/?index=%@&imgIndex=0",backendURL,userImg.userID];
                          imageManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
                          [imageManager GET:imageURL parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable imgResponse) {
                              User *user = userImg;[users objectAtIndex:i];
                              user.profilePic.image = imgResponse;
                              [usersWithImage addObject:user];

                              if (i == users.count-1) {
                                  success(usersWithImage);
                              }
                          } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
                          }];
```

It ''works'' but it just loads the last image in as all the image, i've also tried: https://github.com/robertmryan/AFHTTPSessionOperation/ same result

EDIT/ADD:

```
NSMutableArray *users = [NSMutableArray new];
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
for (id acResult in responseObject) {
  User *user = [[User alloc]initWithId:[acResult valueForKey:@"index"] name:[acResult valueForKey:@"name"]];
  NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image/?index=%@&imgIndex=0",backendURL,user.userID];
  dispatch_group_enter(group);
  [imageManager GET:imageURL parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    user.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(responseObject, 1);
    [users addObject:user];
    dispatch_group_leave(group);     // leave if successful
    } 
failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    dispatch_group_leave(group);     // leave if not
    }];
}
```

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  success(activities); //This is never called 
});
Also i have control over how many users arrive (only 10 per call) but i have no idea which id they have.

Comment: When you say "just loads the last image", have you confirmed how many times `GET` is being called inside that `for` loop? Also, what is `profilePic` inside `User` object? It looks like that might be an image view, but you really shouldn't have UI objects inside your model.

Comment: By the way, where is `userID` set. I don't see you setting that when you download the list of users. So how does this know what `userID` value to use?

Comment: A final observation: I might suggest checking out a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com), which is helpful in diagnosing these sorts of issues. You can watch the requests and responses in an independent tool, and it makes it really easy to identify the source of the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the fast response SO much! Also all the great observations! I have UIImageView inside my User model but nothing it's not connected to a view, is this a problem should i store it as NSData instead?
I did believe that the error was in if (i == users.count-1) {
    success(usersWithImage);
} But i wasn't able to figure anything else out. As i've mentioned i tried the NSOperation and i have also tried dispatch queues, the problem is my dispatch_group_notify never fires. I've updated my code in the example so you can see it. Will check Charles out! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `User` object should hold the `NSData` of the asset, not the `UIImageView`. But as discussed below, it should be loaded in a just-in-time manner. If you want to do a little "preheating" downloading the images for adjacent rows, too, you can do that, but it's a little more complicated. But you want to avoid problem that user quickly scrolls down to the 100th row, you don't want them waiting for the previous 99 images. A good lazy loading mechanism, like `UIImageView+AFNetworking`, solves that problem.

Comment: It is not i a tableview it's more in a swipe way like Tinder so they have to ''acknowledge'' all the images show to them as they are layered, wont lazy loading be to slow for this? Or is it fine on most networks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example, you have:

```
if (i == users.count-1) {
    success(usersWithImage);
}
```

You should either use dispatch group or `NSOperation` wrapper to determine when all the downloads are done, e.g.:

```
imageManager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer]; // you only have to do this once

NSMutableArray *usersWithImage = [NSMutableArray new];

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

for (User *user in users) {
    NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image/?index=%@&imgIndex=0", backendURL, user.userID];
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    [imageManager GET:imageURL parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id imgResponse) {
        user.profilePic.image = imgResponse;   // this line is worrying, though: What are you doing here
        [usersWithImage addObject:user];
        dispatch_group_leave(group);           // leave if successful
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        dispatch_group_leave(group);           // leave if not
    }];
}
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    success(usersWithImage);
});
```

---

I must confess, though, that I find the reference to `user.profilePic.image` a little worrying. Is that a UIKit reference? You shouldn't have UIKit controls in a model object.

---

As a broader issue, if you don't know how many users you might be retrieving, downloading all of the images may not be a wise use of memory and network resources. What if there were 100 users? Downloading the list of 100 users will be quick, but downloading 100 images won't. Generally you should just save the image URL in your model, but don't request the images until the UI needs them (and only download the ones needed, e.g. if only 12 rows visible, only download those 12 images). If you search for "[ios] lazy loading images", you'll probably find many discussions on this topic.

Personally, given that you're already using AFNetworking, I'd be inclined to use the `UIImageView+AFNetworking` category (found in the `UIKit+AFNetworking` folder). This is a really graceful way to do lazy asynchronous image retrieval for a `UIImageView` in a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Is it better practise to save the URL, because i'm trying that and just loading it as you mentioned when the user needs it. But i'm creating an app where the user will swiftly browse through the images (think like how people swipe other people on Tinder) and i would love to just have a batch downloaded and ready to serve to the user. I've also answered the broader issue in the OP.

Comment: Personally, I'd focus on getting a lazy loading of images working first, making sure it's caching correctly and all that good stuff. Then I'd tackle the "preheating" problem of downloading images for adjacent cells after that. But doing this correctly is non-trivial, which is why I was thinking that something like `UIImageView+AFNetworking` might help.

Comment: Yes that is a good point! Alright so you believe i should use dispatch groups? Because the notifier is never fired? It reaches the GET request i can tell from debugging but for some reason never goes inside? Du i need to make the call in a  dispatch_get_main_queue as well? I've updated the latest example using NSData and dispatch groups

Comment: nvm got it to work! Thank you so much for this i have been struggling for a week!